# Is there a Java solution to svnserve like svnkit is to subversion in Java?

Tags: java, svn

Is there a Java solution to svnserve like svnkit is to subversion in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The svnserve program is a lightweight server. You can use svnkit and use scheme svn:// or svn+ssh:// to interact via java with svnserve.

If you are looking for a subversion server implementation in java, I don't think there is something available like that.